# Call shell command in Excel 2010 VBA

Tags: vba, shell, excel, command-line

When I call a shell command in `vba`, the program opens as does the command prompt but nothing happens and no results are obtained.  I can not seem to figure it out and need some help please.

**Command that works**

```
C:\Program Files\BioDiscovery\ImaGene 9.0>ImaGene.exe -batch "C:\Users\cmccabe\Desktop\EmArray\Design\test_11_19_2015.bch"
```

My attempt in excel 2010 using VBA (which opens the program and command prompt, but does not execute the command).

```
Dim Par As String

Par = "dir c:\Program Files\BioDiscovery\ImaGene 9.0\ImaGene.exe -batch "C:\Users\cmccabe\Desktop\EmArray\Design\imagene.bch"
Call Shell("C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c " & Par, 1)
MsgBox ("ImaGene analysis complete")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May not be the best answer but the below solution works for me for similar situation.

open a notepad "c:\Program Files\BioDiscovery\ImaGene 9.0\ImaGene.exe" -batch "C:\Users\cmccabe\Desktop\EmArray\Design\imagene.bch"
save as say "test.bat"

In excel call this .bat file
Dim wshell As Object

Set wshell = CreateObject("wscript.shell")
wshell.Run Chr(34) & "full path\test.bat"

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much, I have been struggling with that. I appreciate your help :).